# Parse data from API response, call function until parameter is received

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a call to an API with jQuery. Since I am new to jQuery I am facing some issues.

First I get an email from the URL using PHP like this: `<?php $email = $_GET['email']; ?>`

I then need to pass the `$email` value in the function below:

```js
function jsCall() {
  var settings = {
    "url": "url to api",
    "method": "POST",
    "timeout": 0,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    // email is dynamic, should pass value from php
    "data": JSON.stringify({"email": "test@gmail.com"}),
  };

  $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    var obj = (JSON.stringify(response));

    //get code, if code is empty call function again in 35 sec
    var code = obj.code; //returns NULL
  });
}
```

When I console.log(response), I get

```
data:Array(1)
  0:
    code:"12315135486132"
```

`console.log(code)` returns `null`

I need to call `jsCall()` 30 sec after page loads. Then if `code` is empty I need run the script every 35 seconds. When `code` has a value I need to redirect the page to `final.php?code=(code_value)`

The first call to the function:

```
setTimeout(function() { jsCall() }, 8000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue you should note is that, given the console output you show, you should be using `response[0].code` to access the value, as the response to the request is an array of objects. Stringifying it is not necessary and will cause issues with the way you attempt to access the properties.

Secondly, all you need is an `if` condition in the AJAX callback in order to either redirect or set the timer to make the AJAX call again. Try this:

```js
function jsCall() {
  var settings = {
    "url": "url to api",
    "method": "POST",
    "timeout": 0,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "data": JSON.stringify({ "email": "<?= $email ?>" }),
  };

  $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
    let code = response.data[0].code;
    if (code) {
      window.location.assign('final.php?code=' + code);
    } else {
      setTimeout(jsCall, 35000); // make AJAX call again in 35 seconds
    }
  });
}

setTimeout(jsCall, 30000); // call 30 seconds after loading
```

Comment: I get an error, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined

Comment: Can you post the actual value of `response`, not the console output of it.

Comment: This is what I get when I cal API in postman:  {
    "error": false,
    "data": [
        {
            "code": "12323123"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: In that case your JS should use `response.data[0].code`. I've updated the answer

Comment: No problem, glad to help